# Проверка обновлений перед запуском приложения

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть небольшое приложение winForms.Я создал его исполнительный(установочный файл) setup.exe .
Само приложение я уже установил на ПК. Хочу чтобы перед его запуском(`Application.Run(new Form1)`) приложение проверяло наличие обновлений по версии.
Я представляю это так:сравнить версии установленного главного файла и другого(нового setup.exe в котором я сделал некоторые изменения)
Как можно сделать проверку обновления перед запуском(это как,например, в стиме) по версии и если оно существует,то обновить установленное на ПК приложение?

Comment: Делаете запрос на сайт, где будете выкладывать обновления и сравниваете версии. См. HttpClient, WebClient, WebRequest.

Comment: А можно как-то без сайта обойтись?

Comment: А где вы будете выкладывать новые версии приложения?

Comment: Так-то нигде не собираюсь) Это для себя приложение.Из VS я его публикую у себя на ПК в папке, а потом устанавливаю

Comment: Тогда в чем смысл вопроса? | Ну, хорошо. Вместо веб-запроса проверяйте определенную папку на наличие новой версии.

Comment: Смысл вопроса в том:Как проверить версию этих файлов и произвести обновление приложения на новую его версию

Comment: Видов обновления куча. Кто то при разнице версий качает установочный файл и автоматом его запускает в тихом режиме; Кто то проверяет все файлы и на основе этих данных составляет список того, что изменилось; Кто то наоборот имеет на сервере информацию о каждом патче, которые программа устанавливает по очереди; Если проект большой, то там и вовсе некоторые используют P2P технологии (торрент) для проверки и скачивания обновления. Как видите вариантов уйма, но у всех у них процедура примерно одинаковая - Берем версию локальную - Сравниваем с версией сервера - Если разные, то качаем - устанавливаем

Comment: Мне просто нужно сравнить версии двух файлов.Меня больше интересует как произвести обновление?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

есть класс: Version. И у этого класса есть оператор сравнения.

```
Version first = new Version("1.1.2.1");
Version second = new Version("2.1.1.1");
bool b = first >= second;
```

У каждого файла есть информация о файле. Та которую ты видишь выбрав "свойства" в контекстном меню.

вот легко нашел в гугле как достается информация о версии файла по адресу (на примере блокнота):

```
FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "Notepad.exe"));
```

---

Теперь по поводу способа обновления. В обновлении есть одна проблемка -- ты не можешь заменять файл который запущен/уже подключен к запущеному файлу (библиотеки). Это обходится очень просто -- создается другой экзешник который и делает сам апдейт. То есть если версии разные -- ты запускаешь апдейтер и вырубаешь свою апликуху. Апдейтер делает апдейт и повторно запускает программу, когда уверен что твоя программа закрыта полностью (делаешь проверку на то открыт ли экзешник/занят ли файл)

Comment: Спасибо за совет как проверить версию!А можете примерно описать,что должно быть в алгоритме файла апдейтера и как этот экзешник создать.Я просто первый раз имею дело с обновлением программы.Раньше об этом не задумывался

Comment: формально, тебе нужно просто окно с надписью "ждите, идет обновление" и запуск установщика твоей программы в сайлент режиме. Я понятия не имею поддерживает ли сайлент режим шарповый инсталлер из коробки. Да и сам я апдейтерами не занимался, так что здесь уже не подскажу деталей. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203300/silent-installation